# server refused to start a shell/command

Tags: linux, centos-7

When I try to open the SSH connection to my CentOS 7 server, I am getting an error

> "server refused to start a shell/command"

Only after the restart, I am able to connect to the server. As per the Grafana dashboard data, the memory usage is only 30% and CPU load is also very low.

Any pointers to identify the root cause of this problem?